# How to write POST method with binary input for Microsoft Cognitive Service API

Tags: c#, post, unity-game-engine

Microsoft cognitive services API supports two input methods within the POST body: raw image binary or image URL. From using the online test console for this API, I know what the HTTP request should look like.

```
`POST https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Faces HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: api.projectoxford.ai
Content-Length: 125
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••

{"url":"someImageURL"}`
```

I am making the request with UnityWebRequest and what I have so far is

```
string url = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/analyze?visualFeatures=Faces";
UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(url, "POST");
www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
www.SetRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", APIKEY);
```

How do I include my byte[] image into this request?

Answer (score 0):

I have only figured it out with a WWW from Unity, not the UnityWebRequest.

I succeeded with this Code:

```
    // Add WWW Headers needed
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    var headers = form.headers;
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream";
    headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = Key;

    //Start WWW Request
    WWW www = new WWW(url, image, headers);

    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
```